# How to create an object on the basis of some condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

How to achieve below kind of thing?

```
dynamic prod = vid.HasValue ? 
              CatalogRepository.GetProductDetailByProductId(pid.Value, vid)
            : CatalogRepository.GetProductDetailByProductId(pid.Value);
```

`GetProductDetailByProductId(pid.Value)` returns an Object of `Product` while `GetProductDetailByProductId(pid.Value, vid)` returns an Object of `ProductVariant`.

I am assigning object to a dynamic variable so it should be identified at runtime but it gives me type conversion error at compile time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess you have an error of type CastException.

Cast your first item to an Object, it should compile:

```
dynamic prod = vid.HasValue ? 
               (dynamic)CatalogRepository.GetProductDetailByProductId(pid.Value, vid) : 
               CatalogRepository.GetProductDetailByProductId(pid.Value);
```

The problem appear because when your are using the conditional operator, the compiler look at the first type to determine the type of the whole return, and potentially apply implicit conversion between objects.

```
var s = true ? "s" : 1 // doesn't compile, no implicit conversion between string and int

var f = true ? 2.0F : 1 // compile, implicit conversion exist between float and int
```

Comment: yes my code has type conversion error that's why i asked question.

Comment: +1. Interesting point. Interesting to find this following snippet compiles: `var field = true ? (object) "s" : 1;`.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can't.

Becuase from [`?: Operator (C# Reference)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx)

> Either the type of first_expression and second_expression must be the
>   same, or an implicit conversion must exist from one type to the other

And looks like there is no *implicit conversion* between your `Product` and `ProductVariant`, so..

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
dynamic prod;
if(vid.HasValue)
   prod = CatalogRepository.GetProductDetailByProductId(pid.Value, vid);
else
   prod = CatalogRepository.GetProductDetailByProductId(pid.Value);
```

or alternativly (if the function has simple Optional Default value.)

```
dynamic prod = CatalogRepository.GetProductDetailByProductId(pid.Value, vid??null);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend the use of some sort of union type for this, rather than using dynamic:

```
public class Union<T1, T2>
{
    private readonly T1 _value1;
    private readonly T2 _value2;

    public Union(T1 value)
    {
        _value1 = value;
    }

    public Union(T2 value)
    {
        _value2 = value;
    }

    public T1 Case1
    {
        get { return _value1; }
    }

    public T2 Case2
    {
        get { return _value2; }
    }
}

var prod = vid.HasValue ? 
    new Union<ProductVariant, Product>(CatalogRepository.GetProductDetailByProductId(pid.Value, vid)) :
    new Union<ProductVariant, Product>(CatalogRepository.GetProductDetailByProductId(pid.Value));
```

(I've kept the definition of the Union type short for brevity, but it ideally would be able to indicate which variant was set, handle the wrong variant being read etc).

Comment: @JitendraPancholi, it remains type-safe that way. With dynamic, you can end up with anything. With a union, you'll get just one or other of the two specified types.